# Android Asset to Raw

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to localize my app so that it will display both Spanish and English.  I have most of the localization figured out with one exception.  I have an .xml file that lists questions for my app that I would like to move to a res/raw folder so that I can add locale and have the app translate.

For the most part this has been easy, as I've been able to call most strings from /res using (getResources().getString(R.string."") However I am having difficulty making this call for my current argument.

I have the xml located in res/raw/"".xml

and i am using asset manager at the moment to grab the .xml for the questions

```
 public static List<Question> readQuestions(AssetManager assetManager){

    ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(assetManager.open("questions.xml"));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("question");
        for(int s=0; s<nodeLst.getLength(); s++){
```

Is anyone aware of a way I could make a call to the raw folder to grab the .xml?

EDIT:::

I am attempting to utilize code for inputstream, but i get an error at contexts that says cannot resolve symbol 'context'

```
 public static List<Question> readQuestions(AssetManager assetManager){

    ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    try{
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(in);


        NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("question");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an InputStream for res/raw/questions.xml

```
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
```

This answer assumes you have a Context.  If you are not familiar with getting and using Context in Android I highly recommend taking the time to really understand it.  You won't get far in Android programming otherwise.

There are a lot of answers on StackOverflow already discussing context. Here is one [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Comment: Alright, sorry i am pretty fresh to android programming, could you show me how i could implement this?

Comment: For ways to get a usable context see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android